# Can't Run Go Bin In Terminal

Tags: bash, unix, go, terminal

I have been executing my Golang code on Visual Studio in the terminal for the past few weeks. All of a sudden I am trying to run a program I made, and it does not run in the terminal. I type **go install project** then type **project**. I get **-bash: project: command not found**. In VS it shows **project**, but is not able to open it. I can run the program if I go through the Finder and look in the bin though which is strange. Any suggestions how to correct this?

Comment: First confirm that `project`'s location is no longer on the `PATH`,  then add it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like your `$PATH` environment variable isn't set to include Go binaries. From [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH):

> For convenience, add the workspace's bin subdirectory to your PATH:
>
> ```
> $ export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
> ```

Most people like to add this to their `.bashrc` to persist it across sessions.

Comment: This only appends `/bin` to the last path in `GOPATH`

Answer (score 0):

Windows users will have something like -

```
GOPATH="c:\Users\<username>\code\go"
PATH="...;%GOPATH%\bin"
```

You will want to add this to path within environment variables -

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b2oa.jpg)

1. Download and install Go distribution(the GOROOT variable was set
   automatically)
2. Create new folder wherever you like for your workspace, create there
   3 directories: bin, src and pkg
3. Then go to

   Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> System ->
       Advansed System Settings -> tab Advanced -> Environment Variables ->
       add new system variable by clicking New on System varaibles ->
       Variable name = GOPATH, Variable value =
       Your:\directory\that\you\created
4. When you're done, RESTART your cmd or Bash(that's important) and you
   have your GOPATH set. To be sure run go env and you will see your
   value.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [direnv](https://direnv.net/), instead of adding to `.bashrc`

```
PATH_add $(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

which adds the bin path when working under your golang project directory